# Layout, Icons, Asset/Network Images are not working on Flutter Release APK

Tags: flutter, flutter-release, flutter-apk

this is the first time I have encountered this problem, where App Layout, Icons, Asset/Network Images are not working on Flutter Release Build.

I already tried cleaning, building multiple times but no luck.

**android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
   <application
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  bottom_picker: ^1.7.0
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.0
  vertical_tab_bar_view: ^0.0.1
  extended_masked_text: ^2.3.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  jiffy: ^5.0.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2
  image_picker: ^0.8.4
  
  flutter_statusbarcolor_ns: ^0.4.0
  
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  titled_navigation_bar: ^5.0.0-nullsafety.0
  flutter_vector_icons: ^1.0.0
  loading_indicator: ^3.0.2
  
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
  
  dio: ^4.0.4  
  get: ^4.6.1

  google_sign_in: ^5.2.4
  google_fonts: ^2.3.1  

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

**DEBUG AND RELEASE MODE MODE**
[image]

[image]

Comment: If I were you I would simply add a Future<String> that downloads and parses a simple JSON file in release mode and then test that to see what error it receives. If it's a network error then it could be DNS related. Could you test that please?

Comment: This is not a network problem since my other app is working fine and they have the same APIs

Comment: When you try to load these images, what error are you getting in release mode in your Flutter app?

Comment: No errors received, only images/icons not displaying. As u can see above debug and release is different.

Comment: Please could you try loading your image with NetworkAssetBundle? That way you can receive errors if there are any. Here is a sample code on how to do that: https://github.com/vandadnp/flutter-tips-and-tricks/blob/main/source/network-image-retry-in-flutter.dart

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

In your pubspec.yaml add:

```
assets:
    - assets/yourimage.png
```

Then, you can call your img like:

```
return const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/yourimage.png'));
```

Comment: what's the difference between assets/yourimage.png and image/yourimage.png? I have image folder

Comment: there isn't difference, is the name of your folder